# How to prevent Activity with Fragment crashing when coming back from background?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

In my App, which uses an `AppCompatActivity`, I have a main `Activity` and everything else is displayed using `Fragment`s.

However, I have noticed, when I press the home button and do something else on the phone. When I get back to the app, it crashes with an "unfortunately application has closed" error.

What I understood from my research is that the `Activity` and everything else gets destroyed. Once the App is opened again, everything is lost and so the application don't know what to do and it crashes.

What can I do in a case like this?

I would be happy if when the application gets re-opened it will just restart, or even better just display resume where the application left earlier.

What can I do to prevent my app from crashing?

Comment: I would recommend reading Activity & Fragment lifecycles in order to implement the lifecycle events : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/#Fragment_Lifecycle

Comment: If your app crashes, please include relevant logs. You should be able to gather something from adb logcat for this particular issue. I guess you are simply missing a constructor or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Android monitor window or firebase console if integrated with firebase crash analytics for exact exception error message.

One possibility could be error something like this,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1341)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1352)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
```

This can be solved by using `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of this `commit()`.

refer this for more info http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html